# how do you solve first order differential equation like this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have this ODE with $t\in1,...,T$ and a function B depend on t
$$B'(t)=1-aB(t)$$
With boundary condition
$$B(T)=0$$

I tried
$$B(t)=t-a\int B(t)dt$$
then I don't know how to proceed from there.
the answer should be
$$B(t)=\frac{1-C(t)}{a}$$
with $$C(t)=exp(-a(T-t))$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Look up the method of integrating factors. (It's usually one of the first things taught in a class about differential equations.)

Comment: The first step is to classify the ODE; does it look like it's linear?

Comment: You have $C(t)=1-aB(t)$. Now compute $C'(t)$ and compare with the differential equation.

Comment: @HansLundmark thanks for the hint, it has been a long while and I almost forgot the trick. can you take a look at my answer to see where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

as suggested i searched the integrating factor.
$$IF:e^{\int a dt}=e^{at}$$
$$B'(t)+aB(t)=1$$
$$B'(t)e^{at}+aB(t)e^{at}=e^{at}$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}(B(t)e^{at})=e^{at}$$
intergrate both sides
$$B(t)e^{at}=\int e^{at}$$
$$B(t)e^{at}=\frac{1}{a}e^{at}+C$$
substitute boundary condition $B(T)=0$
$$C=-\frac{1}{a}e^{aT}$$
so we have
$$B(t)=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a}e^{a(t-T)}$$
$$B(t)=\frac{1-c(t)}{a}$$ where $c(t)=e^{-a(T-t)}$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The very last step is wrong. You somehow lost the factor $1/a$ in $C=-e^{at}/a$ when substituting the value of $C$ back into your formula for $B(t)$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you, error corrected